Adding 240 V Circuit Through Attic
I am planning to add a new 240 V circuit to install a induction style range.  There is an abandoned 240 V outlet at the location when a gas range was added however this is a 2 wire system without neutral which in my understanding would not be appropriate for modern ranges.
The issue I have is that our attic is extremely difficult to access after the living room ceiling was vaulted prior to us moving in.  This is made more difficult by recently added fiberglass blow in insulation.  None of the existing wiring utilizes guard strips or bored holes. The length of the attic run is ~40'
In an effort to simplify the process and avoid too much back-and-forth in the attic I am considering installing conduit from the junction box where THHN wire will enter the attic from the service panel via outdoor PVC to the junction box that descends into the kitchen wall where I would transition to Romex. NM Tubing (smurf) seems appealing however I cannot tell if this can be utilized for a 240v circuit and how it needs to be secured.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

If the range doesn't have a timer it probably doesn't need a neutral.

All standard conduit types can be used for 120V or 240V - really no difference. In the US a 240V circuit is 120V to ground from each hot conductor. Plus the insulation for most wire types is rated for 600V (that allows for use in all kinds of residential and commercial applications).
The issue is considering which type of conduit to use. Conduit that is subject to damage - typically that means above ground and below 8' - generally needs to be PVC schedule 80 (as opposed to schedule 40) or certain types of metal conduit. Conduit also needs to be secured at various intervals, which depends on the type of conduit, but that isn't a big deal.
Transitioning to Romex is certainly OK. But if you are running conduit most of the distance then it makes sense to stick with conduit everywhere.
I highly recommend a hard-wired setup rather than plug/receptacle, unless the new appliance requires a plug/receptacle configuration. That removes a key point of failure with no real downside.

I like the thought of a single wire run from the service panel to the oven, however I do not know how I would add conduit through the wall. As there is currently old Romex to the location I figured I’d probably be able to pull the new 8/3 Romex through that route.

@SaunaBuilder you could open up the walls to run conduit.  Invasive, but possible (obvs depending on construction—concrete walls, probably not possible).
